# How to print the value of a cell you find into a text box in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0yBa.png)We are trying to write a code that, given a site name (column) and SKU (row), the value of the resulting cell gets shown in a text box. We've gotten to the point where we have the cell number, ie. E16, but we can't figure out how to print the value of E16 into the text box. txtPrice.value in the last line is supposed to be what gets posted in the text box, but it keeps coming out empty

```
Private Sub btnGO_Click()
Dim rowNum, cellNum As Variant
rowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(txtSKU.Value, 
Worksheets("AllSites").Range("B:B"), 0)
If IsError(rowNum) Then MsgBox "SKU not found": Exit Sub
If cbxSite.Value = "Fairburn" Then
    cellNum = "C" & rowNum
        ElseIf cbxSite.Value = "Aberdeen" Then
    cellNum = "D" & rowNum
        ElseIf cbxSite.Value = "University Park" Then
    cellNum = "E" & rowNum
        ElseIf cbxSite.Value = "Roanoke" Then
    cellNum = "F" & rowNum
        ElseIf cbxSite.Value = "Lathrop" Then
    cellNum = "G" & rowNum
        Else: cbxSite.Value = "Redlands"
    cellNum = "H" & rowNum
If IsError(cellNum) Then MsgBox "Site not found": Exit Sub
txtPrice.Value = Worksheets("AllSites").Cells(cellNum).Value
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to use `.Range(cellNum)` instead of `.Cells(cellNum)` because of how you built the `cellNum` string.

Comment: Even with .Range instead of .Cells no value is being saved under txtPrice

Comment: What is `cbxSite.Value`? Does `cellNum` actually get populated?  If it does, is there anything in that cell?  If you do `MsgBox Worksheets("AllSites").Range(cellNum).Value` does it show anything?

Comment: cbxsite.value is a combobox that lists 6 sites that a user can choose from. 
cellnum is a variable created based on what column the site is listed in (ex. the site Aberdeen is the column header of column D). Therefore cellNum is storing the column letter and row number (ex. D10) to display a price associated with those two restrictions. 
Then in the text box labeled txtPrice I want the price that is in D10 to be displayed.
msgbox doesn't display anything.

Comment: Ok, if the MsgBox is also not displaying anything, then it sounds like there's nothing in that cell.  Do a `MsgBox cellNum` to verify that cellNum is built correctly, and then manually verify that cell, on sheet "AllSites" isn't blank.

Comment: I posted a link in my original post to the matrix I'm trying to get prices from. What we're trying to do is based off the user's input of the location and the SKU to display the price in the textbox txtPrice based of the matrix

Comment: An image doesn't really help.  You'll need to troubleshoot your actual workbook.  You'll still need to verify that `cellNum` is built correctly and is pointing to the proper cell, and then manually verify that the cell it's pointing to isn't blank.  It sounds like the cell it is pointing to is blank.

Comment: You might also want to try using `.Range(cellNum).Text` instead of `.Value`, but note the return won't be a true number in the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the structure of your `If` statement.  Your `End If` statement is in the wrong place.  This caused Excel to insert a colon after your `Else` statement.  Using a colon is a way to put two statements on the same line.  So the effect of this is that if none of the other `If` & `ElseIf` condtions are met, then this statement `cellNum = "H" & rowNum` will always execute and probably directs cellNum to a blank cell.

Even if one of the other `If` conditions is met, then the code is skipping the part that sets the textbox value because everything between `Else:` and `End If` is part of the `Else:` clause so those statements don't get executed if any of the other `If` conditions evaluate to True.

So you need to change the `Else:` condition to antoher `ElseIf` and move the `End If` statement below that block.

Additionally, you need to change `.Cells` to `.Range` as others here have noted.

```
Private Sub btnGO_Click()

    Dim rowNum, cellNum As Variant

    rowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(txtSKU.Value, Worksheets("AllSites").Range("B:B"), 0)

    If IsError(rowNum) Then MsgBox "SKU not found": Exit Sub

    If cbxSite.Value = "Fairburn" Then
        cellNum = "C" & rowNum
    ElseIf cbxSite.Value = "Aberdeen" Then
        cellNum = "D" & rowNum
    ElseIf cbxSite.Value = "University Park" Then
        cellNum = "E" & rowNum
    ElseIf cbxSite.Value = "Roanoke" Then
        cellNum = "F" & rowNum
    ElseIf cbxSite.Value = "Lathrop" Then
        cellNum = "G" & rowNum
    ElseIf cbxSite.Value = "Redlands" Then
        cellNum = "H" & rowNum
    End If

    If IsError(cellNum) Then MsgBox "Site not found": Exit Sub

    txtPrice.Value = Worksheets("AllSites").Range(cellNum).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, we figured it out yesterday, started everything over and copied/pasted the code and it magically worked!

Comment: That's great!  If this was the solution, can you please mark it as the solution?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use something like `Cells("H6").Value`. It should be `.Range("H6").Value`.

```
'where cellNum is a string something like "H6"
txtPrice.Value = Worksheets("AllSites").Range(cellNum).Value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Textbox.Text = Worksheets("AllSites").Cells(cellNum).Value
```

Comment: Still no value is being displayed under the textbox

Comment: What if: txtPrice.Text = Worksheets("AllSites").Range(cellNum).Value ?